# Using Linq to select the first and last values

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I want to get just the first and last values in a date range. I have the following code:

```
  using (var myEntities = new dataEntities())
  {
      var myValues = (from values in myEntities.PointValues
                      where values.PointID == dataValue && values.DataTime >= fromDate && values.DataTime <= toDate
                      orderby values.DataTime
                      select new BarChartValue
                      {
                          Time = values.DataTime,
                          Value = values.DataValue
                      }).ToList();
      var myBarChart = new List<BarChartValue> { myValues.First(), myValues.Last() };
      return myBarChart;
  }
```

This seems inefficient to me as I select the entire date range values initially. I can't seem to find a way to put first and last into the select command. Surely there must be a way to do this?

In response to Svick.

So, if I do this:

```
      var firstValue = (from values in myEntities.PointValues
                      where values.PointID == dataValue && values.DataTime >= fromDate && values.DataTime <= toDate
                      orderby values.DataTime
                      select new BarChartValue
                      {
                          Time = values.DataTime,
                          Value = values.DataValue
                      }).First();
      var lastValue = (from values in myEntities.PointValues
                        where values.PointID == dataValue && values.DataTime >= fromDate && values.DataTime <= toDate
                        orderby values.DataTime
                        select new BarChartValue
                        {
                            Time = values.DataTime,
                            Value = values.DataValue
                        }).Last();
```

Is that the best way to do it? I don't have any profiling tools (or if I do, I'm unsure how to use them).

The solution as provided by svick is:

```
      var myValues = (from values in myEntities.PointValues
                      where values.PointID == dataValue && values.DataTime >= fromDate && values.DataTime <= toDate
                      orderby values.DataTime
                      select new BarChartValue
                          {
                              Time = values.DataTime,
                              Value = values.DataValue
                          });
      var myBarChart = new List<BarChartValue> { myValues.First(), myValues.OrderByDescending(p => p.Time).First() };
```

A lot of this comes from my lack of understanding of the difference between IQueryable, IEnumerable and List. Here is a good explanation that helped me understand a bit more of what's going on:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844660/differences-between-iqueryable-list-ienumerator

Comment: Looks like Last() might be implemented already potentially?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354927%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.  Guess it might depend on your Target framework though.  As a query do you know why you couldn't use that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is to remove the `ToList()` from your query. This would change your code from making a single query that returns many values to two queries, each returning a single value.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: @Family Yeah, except that you don't need to repeat yourself. You should still have `myValues` (but without `ToList()`) and just call `myValues.First()` and `myValues.Last()`, like before.

Comment: Just in case others have a similar problem. I couldn't use myValues.Last(), I had to use myValues.OrderByDescending(p => p.Time).First();

Comment: @svick a query.  Does First() on the IQueryable interface produce SQL (if that's the database) like Select top 1 * ?

Comment: @dreza Yeah, that's exactly what it should do.

Answer (score 1):

Create the base query:

```
var myValues = (from values in myEntities.PointValues
                where values.PointID == dataValue && values.DataTime >= fromDate && values.DataTime <= toDate
                select new BarChartValue
                {
                    Time = values.DataTime,
                    Value = values.DataValue
                })
```

Then build up the first and last query:

```
var firstAndLast = myValues.OrderBy(x => values.DataTime).Take(1)
                    .Union(
                        myValues.OrderByDescending(x => values.DataTime).Take(1)
                    ).ToList();
```

This will result in one SQL query if the backend is an SQL database and will not recieve entites which are unnecessary (i think the Last() would download all entities).